# How do I name my ocelot in Minecraft PE?

Tags: minecraft-bedrock-edition

How do I name my ocelot? I have the name tag, but how do I put it on?

Answer (score 2):

An alternative naming method is to name your ocelot spawn egg (creative/commands only) in an anvil, and then use it. The ocelot will be named.

Comment: however, all of the ocelots you spawn using that spawn egg will have the same name until you change the name of the spawn egg again.

Answer (score 1):

According to [this website](https://www.digminecraft.com/getting_started/how_to_use_name_tag.php) 
you use an anvil to put a name on the name tag (you have to change the name from "name tag" to something else, and this will cost XP, so make sure you have enough), and then, with the renamed name tag in your hand, tap on the mob (for PE, most games use right click, LT, L2, Or ZL) to use it. you should see the name above the mob's head.

Answer (score -1):

On mobile, tap and hold on the animal after renaming the name tag. To see the name hover your cursor over the animal.

Comment: This adds nothing to an already posted answer 7 days prior..